# Como pegar o valor que está solto dentro de uma div e ignorar os valores que estão dentro de outras tags dentro da div, usando jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        VALOR PARA SER PEGO
        <span>Esse valor não é pra ser pego</span>
        <span>Esse valor também não é pra ser pego</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Exempliquei quais os valores eu gostaria de pegar, reparem que o "VALOR PARA SER PEGO" está dentro da `div` porém solto lá dentro, não esta dentro de tag `<span>`, como eu poderia fazer para pegá-lo?

Tentei do seguinte modo, porém me traz todos os valores, inclusive os que estão dentro do `<span>`, os que estão dentro do `<span>` não irei usar.

```
$("#tabela > tr > td").text();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
$("#tabela > tr > td").clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
```

Esse link me ajudou a resolver o problema e tem uma explicação do uso de cada função:

http://www.tutorialwebdesign.com.br/jquery-capturar-texto-elemento-pai-sem-o-elemento-filho/